# String manipulation Code Changes

Tags: coldfusion

The Following Code creates the Codes properly but only issues in the following

```
<cfset str = "Previoushistory-Diagnosis= 085.2 : Cutaneous leshmaniasis, Asian desert**Controlled-Diagnosis= 085.2 : Asian desert cutaneous leishmaniasis**Controlled-Diagnosis= 153.2 : Cancer of colon, descending colon**Active-Diagnosis= 209.15 : MAL CARCINOID DESC COLON**151.9 : Stomach cancer= UNCONTROLLED">
<cfset string1 = ''>
<cfset generateLst = ''>
<cfset generateLst = ''>
<cfset generateTextlst = ''>
<cfset generateStr = ''>
<cfloop list="#str#" index="elem" delimiters="**">
<cfset string1 = listAppend(string1, elem,'~')>
<cfset delimis = ":">
    <cfloop list="#string1#" index="k" delimiters="~">
    <cfset getString = GetToken(k,1,'#delimis#')>
    <cfset generateStr = ListRemoveDuplicates(ListAppend(generateStr,getString))>
    <cfset getID = GetToken(k,2,'#delimis#')>
    <cfset generateLst = ListRemoveDuplicates(ListAppend(generateLst,getID))>
    <cfset getText = GetToken(k,3,'#delimis#')>
    <cfset generateTextlst = ListRemoveDuplicates(ListAppend(generateTextlst,getText))>
    </cfloop>
</cfloop>
<cfdump var="#str#"><br /><br>
<cfdump var="#generateStr#"><br /><br />
<cfdump var="#generateLst#"><br /><br />
<cfdump var="#generateTextlst#">
```

generated Outputs

**For generateStr**

```
Previoushistory-Diagnosis= 085.2 ,Controlled-Diagnosis= 085.2 ,Controlled-Diagnosis= 153.2 ,Active-Diagnosis= 209.15 ,151.9
```

**For generateLst**

```
Cutaneous leshmaniasis, Asian desert, Asian desert cutaneous leishmaniasis, Cancer of colon, descending colon, MAL CARCINOID DESC COLON, Stomach cancer= UNCONTROLLED
```

**For generateTextlst**

```
[empty string]
```

Now the Problem lies in

```
<cfdump var="#generateStr#"><br /><br />
<cfdump var="#generateLst#"><br /><br />
```

Now the value for **generateStr** is coming as:

> Previoushistory-Diagnosis= 085.2 ,Controlled-Diagnosis= 085.2
>   ,Controlled-Diagnosis= 153.2 ,Active-Diagnosis= 209.15 ,151.9

can i change it like this

> 085.2 ,085.2 ,153.2 ,209.15 ,151.9

and use the removed values to append to the second list to which they are relevant like this

> Cutaneous leshmaniasis, Asian desert**=Previoushistory-Diagnosis**, Asian
>   desert cutaneous leishmaniasis**=Controlled-Diagnosis**, Cancer of colon,
>   descending colon**=Controlled-Diagnosis**, MAL CARCINOID DESC
>   COLON**=Active-Diagnosis**, Stomach cancer= UNCONTROLLED

i am just confused how do i play with couple of list elements to actually make it happen like the above

Any Guidance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be enough to get you started.  I modified your `cfloop` like this:

```
<cfloop list="#string1#" index="k" delimiters="~">
    <cfset getString = GetToken(k,1,'#delimis#')>
    <cfset getText = Trim(GetToken(getString,1,'='))>    <!--- this returns the text for example Previoushistory-Diagnosis --->
    <cfset getValue = Trim(GetToken(getString,2,'='))>   <!--- this returns the value for example 085.2 --->
    <cfset generateStr = ListRemoveDuplicates(ListAppend(generateStr,getValue))>
    <cfset getID = GetToken(k,2,'#delimis#')>
    <cfset newText = getID & "=" & getText>              <!--- this concatenates the two strings together with = inbetween --->
    <cfset generateLst = ListRemoveDuplicates(ListAppend(generateLst,newText))>
    <cfset getText = GetToken(k,3,'#delimis#')>
    <cfset generateTextlst = ListRemoveDuplicates(ListAppend(generateTextlst,getText))>
</cfloop>
```

Which outputs `generateStr` as:

```
085.2,153.2,209.15,
```

And `generateLst` as:

```
 Cutaneous leshmaniasis, Asian desert=Previoushistory-Diagnosis, Cutaneous leshmaniasis, Asian desert cutaneous leishmaniasis=Controlled-Diagnosis, Cancer of colon, descending colon=Controlled-Diagnosis, MAL CARCINOID DESC COLON=Active-Diagnosis, Cutaneous leshmaniasis, Stomach cancer= UNCONTROLLED=151.9
```

Notice that there is an empty value at the end of the `generateStr` list. This is because the last value in your `str` list does not fit the format of the others.  The value `151.9` is at the beginning instead of after the `=` character.

This in turn throws off the `generateLst` list as well. It makes the last value become `Stomach cancer= UNCONTROLLED=151.9`, which I assume you do not want.

So you will need to play around with this a bit more to finalize what you need. Obviously these are the kinds of problems that you run into when attempting to parse strings of data that are not consistent.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this might work:

```
NewList = ListFirst(generateLst);  //Cutaneous leshmaniasis
for (i = 2; i lte ListLen(generateLst); i++) {
NewList = ListAppend(ListGetAt(generateLst, i) &  "=");  
//Cutaneous leshmaniasis, Asian desert=
TempText = ListGetAt(generateStr, i -1); //Previoushistory-Diagnosis= 085.2
TempText2 = ListLast(TempText, "=");  // 085.2
NewList &= TempText2;  //Cutaneous leshmaniasis, Asian desert=085.2
}
NewList = Replace(NewList, ",", ", ", "all);
```

Comment: Hi Dan, I am exploring your technique now, but facing some issues related to ListGetAt